# configure Git SCM local repository as remote one

Tags: git, github

I have Git-scm local setup in windows server and i would need to make this as my remote repo for client use.

in server side i created a bare repo 
in client side created one empty repo and added the first created repo(in server) as the remote repo.

Since both are in windows, when i try to push the commit from the client machine, getting the error as below

```
    $ git push origin master
ssh: connect to host mywindowsserver port 22: Connection refused
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Here I was trying to achieve below things.

1) The normal users from client machine also can be cloned the remote repo from the server and can push and pull normally ( where the users wont have access to the server machine). How can i guide the users to clone remote repo or granting access on the remote repo over LDAp?

2) is there GUI possible to see the Local repo as we are using github GUI?

Comment: just study this https://www.thewindowsclub.com/github-tutorial

Comment: not helped me.. here i am trying to make a cloned repository from bitbucket as a remote repo for other cloned repository in another machine